# Ajax callback doesn't update label

Tags: asp.net, jquery, repeater

I am using following `$.get` method call `AjaxCallHandler.aspx` page asynchronously.

```
        $.get("AjaxCallHandler.aspx?tc_id=" + tc_id, function (response) {
            //get All lblStatus
            var sel = "span[tc_id=" + tc_id + "]";
            //alert($(sel).text() + "  " + response);
            $(sel).text(response);
        });
```

AjaxCallHandler page returns **pass/fails** based on `tc_id is even or odd`.

```
public partial class AjaxCallHandler : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var str = Request.QueryString["tc_id"] != null ? Request.QueryString["tc_id"] as string : string.Empty;
        int tc_id;
        if (int.TryParse(str, out tc_id))
        {
            Response.Clear();            //clears the existing HTML
            Response.ContentType = "text/plain";  //change content type
            if (tc_id % 2 == 0)
                Response.Write("Pass");    //writes out the new name 
            else
                Response.Write("Fail");
            Response.End();             //end
        }
    }
}
```

I simply bind the response to the Asp.Net lablel (placed inside repeater) with custom attribute `tc_id`, labelStatus is not updated.

Pease note, I see values being updated when executing  `$(sel).text(response);` on Chrome Console.

I tried disabling ViewState for repeater as well as `lblStatus`, which didn't help either.

Comment: where is your javascript defined? is it also in the AjaxCallHandler.aspx? Are you calling the same page?

Comment: @Asdfg, JS has been defined in different, say Caller.aspx & this is where repeater & labels are supposed to be updated.

Comment: @Asdfg AjaxCallHandler.aspx only contains Page_Load code as shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would move the code that handles the response to a [ashx file (Generic Handler)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/353260/ASP-NET-Advanced-Generic-Handler-ASHX)

However you say youre gettig the response correctly , when are you calling this exactly ? after the page loads like this ?

```
 $(function () {
       $.get("AjaxCallHandler.aspx?tc_id=" + tc_id, function (response) {
                //get All lblStatus
                var sel = "span[tc_id=" + tc_id + "]";
                //alert($(sel).text() + "  " + response);
                $(sel).text(response);
            });
    });
```